# Compare camera feed to a stored image using objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in iOS development and I want to create an application that will compare an image stored in the project with the camera preview feed. It must then show a rectangle around the matched image in the preview.

I developed a c++ lib that will do the comparison. I also display the preview, but I want to get the feed and convert it to bytes so I will be able to use the lib.

how can i do that?

Comment: Don't repost your questions. If needed, update your original question and provide further details.

Comment: I edited the last one but it still in hold and I am harry to get the answer

Comment: The last one (and this one) are far too broad to be asked on stack overflow. I suggest you click on the help link above and read the section on asking appropriate questions.

Comment: Thanks man I find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will generate byte format of the image

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSUInteger len = [imgData length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

And i think after that you can use your library.

Comment: thank you, in fact I want to convert the camera feed to bytes not the image, have you any idea

Comment: What do you mean by camera feed?